# Servicing Branch in Standard Branch Plan

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I have a very simple question regarding the Standard Branch Plan.

I understand branching, FI and RI, etc.  What I don't quite understand is how to use the Servicing branch in practice.

My understanding is when it comes time to release, I branch Main -> R1.SP1 (assuming this is my first release, for example) and then *immediately* branch R1.SP1 to R1.  Then set R1 to Read Only.  This I completely understand and like.

Here's what I don't understand:  How and when do R1.SP1, R1.SP2, R1.SP3 get created?

Do I RI SP1 back to main and then branch main to SP2/3/n as time goes on?

Said another way, how are these future SPs populated with changes for their own release/deployment?

For example, if a customer reports a bug in R1, where do I check code out from to make this change and where do I check in/commit the changed/fixed code back into?  Do I check in to the SP1 branch? (Because the R1 branch is read only).  Then what?

I guess I am asking where is my sustaining development happening to create the future SPs for R1 and how do these get created and prepped for their own releases/deployment?

A very simple step by step scenario example would be most helpful/appreciated.

Please, if my question is not clear, let me know and I will do my best to revise it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a TFS specialist, but what I read is:

> 1. Developers only need to check in once based on which release vehicle the change is for (i.e. Hotfixes go into the product `HOTFIX` branch).
> 2. No need for baseless merges. Create a natural merge path back to `MAIN` by creating a hierarchal branch structure based on your release vehicles.
> 3. Reduce risk of regressions. By creating a parent/child branch relationship between `MAIN->SP->` and `HOTFIX` branches changes are naturally merged into future release (i.e. `Hotfixes` merge into the `SP` branch on their way to `MAIN`) reducing risk of bug regressions in future releases.
>
> After the release branches are created changes from `MAIN` you should not merge (`FI`) into the release branches.
>   **Changes should merge – one way – from `RELEASE` to `MAIN`.
>
>   Also, changes should always merge through intermediate branches (i.e. `RELEASE` -> `HOTFIX` -> `SERVICEPACK` -> `MAIN`) to ensure that bug fixes remain consistent in subsequent releases**.

[image: Advanced branch Plan]

I think that last section explicitly mentions how the workflow of merges should go once a version has been released into production.
It should go back to main until enough has been consolidated in order to create a new set of ship vehicles (from servicing, where you choose a version to start your new SPx, to Hoyfix.spx, to release.spx)

---

The [OP user1448758](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448758/user1448758) points out in the comment the article [**Where do I fix a production defect?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/03/22/where-do-i-fix-a-production-defect.aspx) which mentions:

> The `Release` branch is a child of the `hotfix` or `servicing` branch, rather than in a separate branching structure. **This allows you to have multiple active release sets (consisting of `Service` Pack, `Hotfix`, `Release` branches) for each of the minor or major releases you need to support in parallel**.
>   The hotfix would be applied to the specific release the bug is found in, and then merged (RI) to `Main` and possibly into vNext development branches.
>
> Since the development branches are working on `vNext` work after `vCurrent` is released, I discourage you from fixing defects found in `vCurrent` (post-release) in the `vNext` development branch.
>   After you release `Sprint 1`, you should fix defects (post-release) in `Sprint 1` on the **`release`** side, and fix bugs (pre-release) in Sprint 2 on the `development` side (`vNext`).

**`Release` is a child of `hotfix`**. **At the time you create the release, the contents of `hotfix` and release are the same**.
`Release` is made read-only and `Hotfix` is available for making defect fixes against what was released.

> **The problem with inverting the structure, is you cannot move a `hotfix` to `Main` without going through `Release`, and doing so means you no longer have a copy of the code as released**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your considered answer. So, taking your diagram above, let's say that I have only released r1.  I've created the hotfix and release r1.sp0 branches and built my .exe from the release branch, and set it to read only.  Now, 1 week after the r1 release a user calls with a bug.  First, where should I check the code out from to start working on it?  Is it from the read only r1 branch?

Comment: Second, once I've made the code fix, where do I check into?  The r1 branch is read only so I assume I am checking it in (i.e. commit) to the hotfix branch then merging it back to into servicing and then main.  Is this correct?  Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Hi @VonC. I think I found an article that answers my question: ["Where do I fix a production defect?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/03/22/where-do-i-fix-a-production-defect.aspx). I think at this point I just need to practice this approach to get the answers to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1448758 good link: I have included the relevant extracts in the answer for more visibility.