# Git philosophy: how to get "master" branch to "production" branch?

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, azure, github

Pretty sure I'm misunderstanding git.

### My goal

- I have a private repo on github with a "master" branch.
- I would like to also have a production branch, which I will push all my changes from master to.
- I would then like to connect it to Azure and tell Azure to automatically deploy from the production branch.

### Question

How do I best accomplish this? Initially I was thinking it was with "git push", but I believe that's for remote repositories, and so I'm now wondering what the best practice is to merge the "master" branch to the "production" branch.

Or, am I thinking about the whole thing wrong?

Thanks -- looking forward to putting my Subversion days behind me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(Since I am suppose to share a "wealth of information" ;) ...)</sup>

What you are looking at, when talking about `master` and `production` branches, is a **merge workflow**.

You can define the workflow you need with any Version Control System tool you want, and in term of development lifecycle management, one of the most complete set of merge workflow set is described in this TFS (Team Foundation Server) set, detailed in its [TFS Brancing Guide](http://tfsbranchingguideii.codeplex.com/) and illustrated in this question "[Servicing Branch in Standard Branch Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442851/6309)".
Closer to git, **[git flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)** is another merging workflow quite popular.

But you are using a DVCS, and its *distributed* aspect introduces another (orthogonal) workflow: a *publication* one (your `git push -u origin prod`). See "[Source Control - Distributed Systems vs. Non Distributed - What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473315/6309)"

Publication, part of release management, is quite different from merge, part of development.
By merging `master` to `prod`, you freeze what has been consolidating in development, and mark it as to be released.
By pushing it to GitHub, you start that release process.

Answer (score 2):

When your master branch is ready to be put in production, you merge it to the production branch, and then push this production branch to the github repo.

Comment: Short, to the point, and solved my immediate solution. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around? The master is the live website, and the production branch is where you do your coding?

Comment: theres always confusion on master. technically you can opt not to use it at all. have {develop} - {test} - {production}. very simplified..from CI/CD which can be {develop} - {unit} - {integration} - {production}, whereby production branch builds/deploys every day. you develop from {develop} branch with feature/AAA then merge it back where you can put in a pipeline (jenkins/gitlab) that pulls from develop (via trigger webhooks) and test. on passing test push to prod. very simplified version.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at the git pages for [branching workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) to establish your repository management plan. Further, [Von C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=answers) shares a wealth of information on the git ecosystem. Browsing his answers may be prove very useful. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch) is also extremely helpful for tracking remote branches.

Comment: Thank you for this additional information! These guides are going to prove quite valuable.